# How to convert from String to EnvelopesAPI

Tags: docusignapi

I save the created envelope in my database as a string to get it later.

My problem here , is that i want to convert that string to type  EnvelopesApi to call some methods. I tried to convert it  to JSON Object but the same thing, i didn't  find the right way to convert.

Any idea please

Comment: What is the use case for doing that? It would be simpler to save the created envelope id and use that in subsequent methods.

Comment: @bendowlingtech , thank you for your comment. Yes, i did it but i usually get problem . Here is the link to my issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68119459/docusign-get-envelope-information-returns-empty

Comment: Please EDIT your question to explain what is the problem you are trying to solve. Also, what language/framework are you using? Your other question has an answer.