# DocuSign get envelope information returns empty

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to get envelope information from DocuSign  by using rest template like this :

```
       final String uri = "http://demo.docusign.net/v2.1/accounts/"+ session.getAccountId() +"/envelopes/"+results.getEnvelopeId() ; 
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
        ResponseEntity<String> res = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, String.class);
```

Am passing the right account id and envelope id , but i get a nullable response (res variable):
[image]

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Your URI begins with `http://` - all DocuSign API calls must be secured via HTTPS. Updating your prefix to `https://` should resolve.

The HTTP response code of 301 is a hint - DocuSign is attempting to redirect you to the https endpoint, but it looks like that's not succeeding.